# MVC alternative route for custom route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

i need some help.
I'm working with MVC 5, in VS 2015, and i want to configure some routes in my project.

First, i have a "Default" route, that is it:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "Tipoou.Controllers" }
        );
```

This route is used for the common actions, like:
`localhost/auth/login` or **localhost/sell/`

But, I have an Area, that the name is Company. And, I want to get the name company in the url, like this: `localhost/companyname/{controler}/...`

So, I did something like this (in the `CompanyAreaRegistration.cs`) :

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Company_default",
    "{company}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

But, the Default route just stop working (thrown the 404 error). And, ALL the name that I put after localhost, it's calling the Company Area.

Can someone help me?

Can i do something like: try the Company route, if fail, try the Default?

Comment: Do you have multiple company names, or only the text "company"? Try deleting the curly braces around "company", i.e. "company/{controller}/{action}/{id}",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove curly braces from company name in the template of route:

```
context.MapRoute("company_default",
                "company/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Also your controller class needed the following RouteAreaAttribute:

```
[RouteArea("company", AreaPrefix = "company")]
public class MyTestController : Controller
{ 
    ...
}
```

Comment: It worked! In the real, i figure out it on the past, but is kind the same adjust that i have made on my project. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great that my answer was applicable in your case!